# Pytesseract Error - no such file or directory Error during processing

Tags: python

I am computing quite a simple Image to text using Pytesseract in Python. However, I keep having this error

> pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, 'Tesseract Open Source OCR
> Engine v5.0.0-alpha.20200328 with Leptonica Error, cannot read input
> file C:\code\img: No such file or directory Error during
> processing.')

I try to place both my image and python files in the same folder but the error is still there. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I am looking for answer to the same issue. If you could resolve it, kindly share the answer. Thanks.

The error on my RHEL server is:

Exception has occurred: TesseractError
(1, "read_params_file: Can't open txt Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v5.0.0-alpha-20201224 with Leptonica Error, cannot read input file /tmp/tess_dx0os76p.PNG: No such file or directory Error during processing.")

Answer (score 1):

It's a permission issue of OS, not pytesseract.
The root cause is that there is no permission for reading that file.
In my project in Ubuntu 20, I moved that folder to another directory and everything is okay.
You can try the same at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046890/libreoffice-cant-access-tmp-files-in-18-04.